# javascript Redirect user to directory based on form input

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

someone give me a part of the answer
[Redirect user to directory based on form input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541015/redirect-user-to-directory-based-on-form-input)

```
<form onsubmit="location.href='http://www.example.org/' + document.getElementById('myInput').value; return false;">
<input type="text" id="myInput" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

the code implement like this in the browser :

http://www.example.com/contact

my issue is :

this address become not working with me **without** adding extension **.html**

like this

http://www.example.com/contact.html

i read about solution in the **.htaccess**

but I'm looking if we can implement this too in java script

so the use just Enter the word **contact** as the example before
and java script do the other ?

regrads

Comment: Opening a "contact.html" page when the URL points at "/contact" is a server-side thing, so it can't be done solely in JS. But why not just use "/contact.html"?

Comment: A very ugly hack would include taking the `contact` keyword from the url and requesting that page using ajax.

Comment: So you want to send the user to contact.html but have the URI be /contact?

Comment: @JosanIracheta  if you tried the code that i mentioned above the user in the input form enter just the word "contact" so after submit will redirect to :
http://www.example.com/contact
because java script have the first part before in the code:

**onsubmit="location.href='http://www.example.com/' + document.getElementById('myInput').value; return false;"**
my website urls must end with **.html**
so i'm looking write **contact** and redirect to **contact.HTML** to work in my site
i get a solution in Apache converting urls 
**so** can i  do this in code? without Apache server?
regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned in the comments, the way to get 100% of what you're asking for is to add a rule to the .htaccess (assuming Apache) that makes the server add the file extension.

The closest I think you could do purely on the client side is to simply add the .html yourself, maybe like this:

```
<form onsubmit="handleFormSubmit();">
<input type="text" id="myInput" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

And then somewhere in  your javascript:

```
function handleFormSubmit() {
    var destinationUrl = 'http://www.example.org/' + document.getElementById('myInput').value + ".html";

    window.location = destinationUrl;
}
```

The biggest problem I see with what you're wanting to do, though, is that you're relying on the user to know what the names of the available pages are, unless you have something more going on on the server side.